# Atomic basin partitioning with electron density grid

Tags: crystallography

I am performing Hirshfeld Atom Refinement (HAR) calculations with XRD data using aspheric atomic scattering factors, which are calculated from wavefunctions optimized in Orca. My crystal structure has substitutional ion disorder, so the Orca calculations involve several possible ion occupancy configurations. I have the resulting .wfn files from Orca for each configuration, and I am able to perform the atomic basin partitioning with these in multiwfn without any problems (using charge density calculated from the wavefunctions). Now I would like to do the same with the calculated electron density map obtained from HAR. I have the crystal structure model available as .pdb and the density map as .cube. There are 242 atoms in the unit cell.  When I read both the pdb and cube files into multiwfn and try the basin analysis (using grid in the memory), the program generates 12k tiny basins. Could you advise what I am doing wrong and how to solve the problem?